# Reference an ext.js store in a different c# project

Tags: c#, javascript, extjs

I want to create an ext.js store that can be shared across c# projects.  I defined my store in the Services project under Scripts/Store/Hierarchies.js.  The store is named NCS.store.Hierarchies.

```
Ext.define('NCS.store.Hierarchies', {
requires: [
    'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    'Ext.data.Operation',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    'NCS.store.SelectedHierarchies'

],
```

In a different c# project I now want to reference this store-

```
Ext.widget({
            id: 'hierarchyPanel',
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: true,
            frame: true,
            title: 'Hierarchy Selector',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'start',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            collapsible: true,
            items: NCS.store.Hierarchies.getComboArray().concat(
            Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                id: 'hierarchyClear',
                text: 'Clear'
            })),
            renderTo: this.constants.hierarchiesId,
            listeners: {
                show: {
                    fn: function (t, o) {
                        t.doLayout();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How do I properly reference this store?  Currently I'm getting a not found error (it's looking in the current c# project url instead of the one that actually contains the store).

```
> GET
> http://localhost/Orchard/NCS.Reporting.PODS/NCS/store/Hierarchies.js?_dc=1405085182757
> 404 (Not Found)
```

I think it should be looking

```
http://localhost/Orchard/NCS.Services.PODS/NCS/store/Hierarchies.js?_dc=1405085182757
```

Also since it's looking under NCS/store I'm wondering if I need to change the folder layout to match my naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ExtJs Loader object -

```
// load up all of our dependencies
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'NCS': Config.RootUrl + 'Modules/NCS.Services.PODS/Scripts'
    }
});
```

I need to specify where to find NCS for ExtJS to locate the correct file.  Now that I have the NCS path loaded I can use the code above to reference NCS.store.Hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider mapping the folder where the scripts are stored as a virtual directory in IIS so that the web server can serve them in response to web requests.